# Generic QuickSort with Performance Optimised Swap for small types

Tags: c, quick-sort

## Overview

A "from scratch" generic quicksort implemented in C, which allows predicate (returning `bool`, like C++ rather than `int` like C), and any type via `void*`.

Using `memcpy` for the `swap()` implementation was the general solution. But this was about twice as slow as declared types for small types (int, float, double etc). So I added a simple "type-size-switch", which worked to restore performance to pre-generic levels.

More types/sizes can be easily added. Including `char*` to sort strings by swapping their pointers - demo included, it uses the `long` case in the type switch on my machine because `long` and `ptr` are both 8 bytes. I know the `memcpy` solution won't handle very large types - would have to use `malloc` or "byte-by-byte swap" it with our own loop.

Uses "C++ iterator" style params `start` and `end` (which is one past the end) rather than C-style `start` and `count`.

### Questions

1. Type-size switch. Is this a reasonable techique hint to the compiler to use registers for optimisation rather than slow generic `memcpy` for small types.
2. Does the above violate the standard? What about using `long` to `swap` a `double` if they happen to be the same size, which is very common?
3. How about the use of `/dev/urandom` use for `srand()` (I know it's not cross-platform).
4. Any other comments?

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef bool (*cmp)(const void*, const void*);

bool less_ints(const void* a, const void* b) {
  return *(const int*)a < *(const int*)b;
}

bool greater_ints(const void* a, const void* b) {
  return *(const int*)a > *(const int*)b;
}

bool less_strs(const void* a, const void* b) {
  return strcmp(*((const char**)a), *((const char**)b)) < 0;
}

void swap(void* x, void* y, size_t size) {
  switch (size) {
  case sizeof(int): {
    int t      = *((int*)x);
    *((int*)x) = *((int*)y);
    *((int*)y) = t;
    break;
  }
  case sizeof(long): { // used by char**
    long t      = *((long*)x);
    *((long*)x) = *((long*)y);
    *((long*)y) = t;
    break;
  }
  default: {
    char t[size];
    memcpy(t, x, size);
    memcpy(x, y, size);
    memcpy(y, t, size);
  }
  }
}

void* partition(void* start, void* end, size_t size, cmp predicate) {
  if (start == NULL || end == NULL || start == end) return start;
  char* storage = (char*)start;
  char* last    = (char*)end - size; // used as pivot
  for (char* current = start; current != last; current += size) {
    if (predicate(current, last)) {
      swap(current, storage, size);
      storage += size;
    }
  }
  swap(storage, last, size);
  return storage; // returns position of pivot
}

void quicksort(void* start, void* end, size_t size, cmp predicate) {
  if (start == end) return;
  void* middle = partition(start, end, size, predicate);
  quicksort(start, middle, size, predicate);
  quicksort((char*)middle + size, end, size, predicate);
}

bool sortcheck(const int* start, int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) {
    if (start[i] > start[i + 1]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

void print(const int* start, int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) printf("%3d", start[i]);
  printf("\n");
}

bool rand_seed() {
  int   seed = 0;
  FILE* fp   = fopen("/dev/urandom", "re");
  if (!fp) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: couldn't open source of randomness");
    return false;
  }
  if (fread(&seed, sizeof(int), 1, fp) < 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: couldn't read random seed");
    fclose(fp);
    return false;
  }
  fclose(fp);
  srand(seed); // nice seed for rand()
  return true;
}

int rand_range(int start, int end) {
  return start + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (end - start + 1) + 1);
}

int main() {
#define size 10000000
  int* data = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
  if (!data) {
    fprintf(stderr, "couldn't allocate memory");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (!rand_seed()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "couldn't seed random number generator");
    free(data);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) data[i] = rand_range(1, size / 2);

  // print(data, size);

  quicksort(data, data + size, sizeof(int), &less_ints);
  // partition(data, data + size, sizeof(int), &less_ints);

  // if (!sortcheck(data, size)) {
  //   fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: data is not sorted!\n");
  //   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  // }
  // print(data, size);
  free(data);

  // string demo
#define str_count 12
  const char* strings[str_count] = {
      "material", "rare",    "fade",      "aloof",  "way",  "torpid",
      "men",      "purring", "abhorrent", "unpack", "zinc", "unsightly",
  };
  quicksort(strings, strings + str_count, sizeof(char*), &less_strs);
  for (int i = 0; i < str_count; ++i) printf("%s\n", strings[i]);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: If your `rand` only returns 15 or 16 bits (which is common) your random ranges won't cover the full range.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thanks, valid point. It's (2^31)-1, ie ~ 2Billion on my machine, and I wasn't really focused on uniform distribution etc. But fair point.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything random in here anyway - sorting should be completely deterministic, and tests need to be reproducible (nothing worse than tests that sometimes pass and sometimes fail - how do you debug that?) At least print the seed used, and allow that to be passed in to reproduce the test.

Comment: Yes, that's true, and I did fix the seed while debugging. But I opened it to generate any possible unforseen edge cases.

Comment: How many platforms' implementations of `memcpy()` did you profile to determine that it always performs weakly with small count?  You're probably reimplementing something that the better compilers are already doing for you (remember that `memcpy()` may be inlined by the compiler, so it likely depends on the optimisation level you ask for, too).

Comment: I used gcc-9 and clang-10 on ubuntu 20.04 with `-O3`. I suspect they used the same underlying `libc` implementation of `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 2):

> Type-size switch. Is this a reasonable techique hint to the compiler to use registers for optimisation rather than slow generic memcpy for small types.

Why do you think that `memcpy()` has not already implemented this optimization itself? Do you have timing data to suggest this optimization works and improves performance?

> Does the above violate the standard? What about using long to swap a double if they happen to be the same size, which is very common?

On a lot of systems `long` and `int` are the same size. In that case your `switch()` will fail to compile (I think).

> How about the use of /dev/urandom use for srand() (I know it's not cross-platform).

If it does not exist then why not fall back on the classic `time(NULL)` rather than generating an error.

> Any other comments?

Let the compiler do the work of calculating array sizes:

```
const char* strings[] = {
                // ^^   Notice empty braces forces the compiler to 
                //      calculate the correct size based on the initialization values.
    "material", "rare",    "fade",      "aloof",  "way",  "torpid",
    "men",      "purring", "abhorrent", "unpack", "zinc", "unsightly",
};

const int str_count = sizeof(strings) / sizeof(strings[0]);
                   // This trick works even if the array has size 0
                   // because the sizeof is done at compile time
                   // and thus strings[0] is never actually accessed
                   // just type information is retrieved.
```

Comment: Sure thanks. Aware of that technique and use it often.

Comment: Yes I did time it. Without the `sizeof()` switch just using `memcpy` for small types it is twice as slow. As soon as I made `swap()` type aware the performance improved by 2x.

Comment: I like the idea of `time(NULL)` as a fallback. I guess if I really cared enough about quality randomness, I probably shouldn't be using `rand()` anyway?

Comment: I am compiling with clang-10 on ubuntu 20.04 btw. `clang  -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror`

Comment: Interesting point on the duplicate sizes. You're right. If I add a case for `double` (which is same size as `long` on my machine) then it fails to compile. Might be safer as an `if / else if / else`?

Comment: I timed it with `if / else if / else` and it's marginally faster than with `switch`, so that's definitely the way to go.

Comment: If you use `if/else if/else` you will loose performance. You could add `#if sizeof(long) != sizeof(int)`

Comment: Both `gcc-9.3` and `clang-10` exhibit the significant perf improvement from the `size` `switch/if`. `gcc` is faster overall, but has a > 2x difference. `clang` is slightly slower but has a ~ 1.75x difference.

Comment: Yeah, not so on my machine with above compilers. `if/else` is marginally faster than switch, don't ask me why.

Comment: `marginally faster` => branch prediction. The trouble is for times when the predication fails. `switch` will be faster in most situations.

Comment: That could well be, yes. Either way, I am super surprised that this "hack" (which is what it feels like) gets me 1.75 -> 2.2x performance improvements for small primitive types..`switch` or `if/else`, because the type will be same for entire sort, so the branch predictor is doing good work.

Comment: Perhaps there is some compiler optimisation magic/inlining which is possible when the type is known in the local source file, but not possible when linking against a shared object file (memcpy) from libc?